# Add rows to an Array with a foreach loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, foreach, addition

I am struggling with this question.

**What do I have:**

- PHP array variable $v that goes to a javascript array variable with json_encode;
- An array called "data" populated by hand.

**What I want:**

- To use a foreach loop or other best solution to populate the content of $v to "data";

*Here is the first structure I had:*

```
    var counter = <?php echo json_encode($v); ?>;

    new Morris.Line({
      element: 'visit-chart',

      data: [
        { "period": '2014-07-01', value: 70 },
        { "period": '2014-07-02', value: 59 },
        { "period": '2014-07-03', value: 130 },
      ],

      xkey: 'period',
      ykeys: ['value'],
      labels: ['Views']
    });
```

*This is what counter variable retrieves:*

```
[{"id":"6","day":"2014-09-06","views":"7"},{"id":"5","day":"2014-09-05","views":"3"},{"id":"4","day":"2014-09-04","views":"6"},{"id":"3","day":"2014-09-03","views":"2"},{"id":"2","day":"2014-09-02","views":"15"}];
```

What I want now is to change the values of "period" and "value" by the values of "day" and "views" of the "counter" array variable.

I tried this:

```
 var counter = <?php echo json_encode($v); ?>;

new Morris.Line({
  element: 'visit-chart',

  data: [
      counter.forEach(function(entry) {
           { "period": entry[days], value: entry[views] },
      });
  ],

  xkey: 'period',
  ykeys: ['value'],
  labels: ['Visualizações']
});
```

Can anyone help me? I'm a begginer at jQuery by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var counter = <?php echo json_encode($v); ?>;
var data =[];
for(i=0;i<counter.length;i++){
    data.push({"period":counter[i].day, "value":counter[i].views})
}
new Morris.Line({
  element: 'visit-chart',
  data: data,
  xkey: 'period',
  ykeys: ['value'],
  labels: ['Visualizações']
});
```

Comment: I worked, thanks man, appreciated your help. I can't vote you up, but if you vote my question I can do that. Thanks again